# How to prove $\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous?

Tags: limits, continuity

$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}  \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & \text{ for } (x,y) \ne (0,0)\\ 
                       0 & \text{ for } (x,y) = (0,0) 
\end{cases}$$

I know how to prove the function is continuous at $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ but I don't know how to prove it is continuous at zero. I know it is possible with the epsilon delta definition but I can't find it.

Comment: Hint: Polar coordinates.

Comment: We didn't discuss much of polar coordinates yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Polar coordinates are useful when our expression has $x^2+y^2$ in the denominator. However, in this case the following is enough: If $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ then
$$\frac{|x^3|}{x^2+y^2}=|x|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\le |x|.$$

Answer (score 2):

if you set $$x = \rho \cos\theta, y = \rho \sin\theta$$ the limit becomes

$$\lim_{\rho \to 0} \frac{\rho^3 \cos^3{\theta}}{\rho^2} = \lim_{\rho \to 0} \rho \cos^3{\theta} = 0 $$

Because $\cos\theta \le 1$, so $|\rho \cos^3{\theta}| \le |\rho| \to 0$